# Assuming $P \neq NP$, do we know whether there are problems which are in $NP$, not in $P$ and are not $NP$ complete?

Tags: computer-science, np-complete

Here's a question.  Have there been any theoretical results showing that if $P \neq NP$, there must exist some problems in $NP$ which are not $NP$-complete and which are not in $P$ either?  Just curious because I've never seen this question addressed.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, this is known as Ladner's theorem, proved by Richard Ladner in 1975. The class of such problems are called [NP-intermediate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-Intermediate). [Here's one proof](http://books.google.com/books?id=47GwSJfb1mQC&pg=PA38) that does "cut and paste" between some problem in P and some NP-complete problem, [here are two](http://blog.computationalcomplexity.org/2003/03/foundations-of-complexity-lesson-16.html), and there are [others](http://www.google.com/search?q=ladner%27s+theorem).

There are also problems that are already *believed* to be neither NP-complete nor in P, like integer factorisation and graph isomorphism, as well as [problems known to be in NP ∩ coNP](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/31821/problems-known-to-be-in-both-np-and-conp-but-not-known-to-be-in-p) but not known to be in P.

Comment: In this connection I can't resist linking to Ryan Williams' excellent explanation of Ladner's theorem on MO: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/9221/what-techniques-exist-to-show-that-a-problem-is-not-np-complete/9253#9253

Comment: @Qiaochu: Thanks, describing it as "cut and paste" seems so boring now. :-)